# How to call a behavioral method from main method in java?

Tags: java, static-methods, method-call

I have a non static method `abc()` in the class that contains `main()` method. Now how to call this method `abc()` from main. Can i create an instance of the class in the same class?

```
public class A
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //how to call abc() here?
    }
    private int abc()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to create an instance of this class in `main()` before asking your question?

Comment: This is very basic programming knowledge. You should try to work through some programming tutorials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to instanciate current class, use this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    A a = new A();
    int value = a.abc();
}
```

Comment: is it possible to create an object of class A inside class A?

Comment: Of course, try it. What you can't do is try to create instance of the same class inside a constructor (you'll get stackoverflow).